# Mysql consulta para obtener fecha de ingreso de un dato a la base de datos

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos en MYSQL y diseñe la tabla para que recibiera respuestas pero no le hice un campo de fecha de realización.  Mi pregunta es si en MYSQL existe una consulta para saber en que fecha se realizo una inserción.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: No existe. Lo ideal sería que agregues un campo para registrar dicho valor.

Comment: Puedes crear un campo al final de la tabla de tipo `datetime`. Luego desde `PHP` insertas la fecha actual con `$variable = "INSERT INTO tu_tabla (NOW())";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me temo que **no** estimado compañero. El tema de auditoria de los registros a nivel de cada tabla se debe llevar en la misma en unos campo date o datetime ya sea para la creación de un registro o la actualización del mismo.

Otra forma, es llevarlo de manera general en otra tabla parametrizada de auditoria para todo un sistema. En este aspecto hay opiniones de lado y lado.

Lastimosamente es lo que puedo acotar respecto a tu pregunta. Saludos.